# Python string nesting under string

Tags: python, string, text

When I run the line of code below, I get the following result:

```
>>> a = ''' this " is what \"is 'needed' \" Please " '''
' this " is what "is \'needed\' " Please " '
```

I want the output to be:

```
' this " is what "is 'needed' " Please " '
```

The problem is `'` is getting replaced by `\'`. 
Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: You are echoing a string object, so the `repr()` representation is shown. This is meant for *debugging output*, easily copyable into a Python script as it is still valid string literal syntax that'll recreate the exact same value.

Comment: You normally want to use `print()` to write the string value itself. Is there any reason you need the outer `'....'` quotes to be part of the printed value?

Comment: I need the outer ' ...' , the whole thing is passed to a function, so can't print it also

Comment: If you are passing it to a function, then *there is nothing wrong here*, the backslashes are not part of the value, only of the representation.

Comment: actually the example is a demo, this "a" is passed into a paramiko session which is a sql query passed into a linux server. The query should only hold " where item = 'Y' " but its coming " where item = Y  " . that is taking Y as a column and not a values

Comment: Right, so you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have mis-diagnosed the problem and asked a question about your diagnosis, not the real problem you were trying to solve. Sounds like you need to use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to print your string:

```
a = ''' this " is what \"is 'needed' \" Please " '''
print(a)
```

Output:

```
this " is what "is 'needed' " Please "
```

or, if you really want the outer quotes:

```
print("'" + a + "'")
```

Output:

```
' this " is what "is 'needed' " Please " '
```

Comment: What if they want those outer single quotes?

Comment: I can't print it basically, this "a" is going to be passed into a function

Comment: But you said: `"I want the output to be:"` (etc). It looks like this is not a problem. Just pass `a` into the function and you are done.

Comment: actually the example is a demo, this "a" is passed into a paramiko session which is a sql query passed into a linux server. The query should only hold " where item = 'Y' " but its coming " where item = \'Y\' "